# USB-C thunderbolt not working anymore - Ubuntu 18.04 + Windows

Tags: usb, 18.04, windows

I have been struggling for the last couple of days to figure out **why my thunderbolt ports (on the left side of the XPS 13) stopped working on Ubuntu 18.04**. The right side USB port works well and charging works on all the ports. Also, because I have a dual boot with Windows 10, I checked if I had the same issues and, indeed, **the USB ports don't work on Windows**. By USB ports not working I mean that neither ethernet, HDMI, external memory nor USB hub are recognized.

I don't know if it is a coincidence but it happened after I tried to find a way to transfer file to my android device. Following this post ([Trying to install android-file-transfer Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038145/trying-to-install-android-file-transfer-ubuntu-18-04-bionic/1038233#1038233)) I did the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/samoilov-lex/aftl-stable/ubuntu artful main"
sudo apt install android-file-transfer
sudo apt install libmtp-common mtp-tools libmtp-dev libmtp-runtime libmtp9
```

Here are the things I noticed so far

- Windows can crash when I plugin a device on the left side (but not always) with a blue screen and a forced reboot
- When it does not crash, Windows shows an error "device not recognized"
- Ubuntu does absolutely nothing when I plugin a device on the left side
- Wifi/bluetooth work fine on both Ubuntu and Windows

I've been trying to solve that non-working USB port issue for a while now and here are the steps I followed:

- I checked that the USB devices worked on other computers and they work fine
- I updated the BIOS through Windows
- I installed all the Windows updates
- I uninstalled and reinstalled all the USB-related drivers in Windows
- I disabled/re-enabled all the USB-related options in the BIOS as suggested in https://www.dell.com/community/Windows-8/XPS-13-9333-USB-Ports-Not-Recognizing-Any-Device/m-p/4565350#M9012
- I disabled the USB security option in the BIOS (Switching from "User security" to "No security") https://eischmann.wordpress.com/2017/06/29/thunderbolt-security-levels-and-linux-desktop/
- I ran all the BIOS and Windows diagnostics/troubleshooter and no errors were detected
- I installed all the latest Ubuntu packages and updated the Kernel
- I turned off the computed and waited a couple of hours (some people on this website thought that it could originate from an overheating)
- I disabled the WIFI/bluetooth that could apparently conflict with the USB ports in term of CPU usage ([18.04: usb or other removable devices are not recognized after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031992/18-04-usb-or-other-removable-devices-are-not-recognized-after-update))
- I tried to disable the USB power management because of some potential problems mentioned in an old post ([2 usb ports stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526082/2-usb-ports-stopped-working))
- I uninstalled the android-file-transfer related packages and removed the repository
- **EDIT**: I tried to check the USB ports using a live USB key but the same error occurs

**I run out of ideas so if anyone has a solution please feel free to reply. Thank you a lot.**

I have a Dell XPS 9370 from 2018 with configuration

```
$ inxi -ACDF
System:    Host: XPS-13-9370 Kernel: 4.15.0-36-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.28.3
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Dell product: XPS 13 9370 serial: N/A
           Mobo: Dell model: 0H0VG3 v: A00 serial: N/A UEFI: Dell v: 1.5.1 date: 08/09/2018
Battery    BAT0: charge: 37.0 Wh 71.1% condition: 52.0/52.0 Wh (100%)
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-8550U (-MT-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB
           clock speeds: max: 4000 MHz 1: 800 MHz 2: 800 MHz 3: 800 MHz 4: 800 MHz 5: 800 MHz 6: 800 MHz
           7: 800 MHz 8: 800 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel UHD Graphics 620
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) driver: i915 Resolution: 3840x2160@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2) version: 4.5 Mesa 18.0.5
Audio:     Card Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel Sound: ALSA v: k4.15.0-36-generic
Network:   Card: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath10k_pci
           IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: 9c:b6:d0:88:8e:5b
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 256.1GB (44.3% used)
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 model: KXG50ZNV256G_NVMe_TOSHIBA_256GB size: 256.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 168G used: 106G (67%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 53.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 342 Uptime: 25 min Memory: 2798.2/7692.8MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.56
```

List of my USB devices

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0489:e0a2 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:58f4 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 27c6:5385  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here are some kernel errors. Notably the "Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?" that happends any time I connect a USB device on one of the left USB port.

```
$ dmesg
...
[  729.934551] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  755.529789] usb usb3-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  755.529931] xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: Command completion event does not match command
[  755.529950] xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: Error while assigning device slot ID
[  755.529960] xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 64.
[  755.529965] usb usb3-port1: couldn't allocate usb_device
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to boot on a USB key with a Linux distro.
The portable Linux distros come with a robust and comprehensive driver set.

If that does not work you probably got a hardware failure.

Comment: I tried to check the USB ports with a live USB key but the same error occurs.

Comment: Amzocks, dit you find a solutions to this? I have the same issue (usb-c is giving me power from the external monitor, but the same xhci_hcd error). Tried installing ubuntu 19.04 but no luck (dmesg now gives me 'Unknown WMI event type 0x12)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I had to send my computer back to the factory. They changed the whole thing and sent it back to me. Apparently it was hardware-related.