# After upgrade from Ubuntu 16 to 18.04, systemd-udevd uses 100% CPU

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, cpu-load

Since I upgraded from Ubuntu 16 to 18.04, CPU usage is high. Sometimes 100% cpu usage, and when that happens we can't do anything. If we check on the process `systemd-udevd`, we find it is using 100% CPU. I have followed an answer to this question: [Ubuntu 18.04 systemd-udevd uses high CPU, conflict with nvidia graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035528/ubuntu-18-04-systemd-udevd-uses-high-cpu-conflict-with-nvidia-graphics) but now I can't use any browser.

I ran the command `sudo mv /lib/udev/rules.d/71-nvidia.rules ~` and now I can't install a new browser or use the old one, and I still have this 100% CPU issue.

[Here's a detailed list of my system hardware](https://justpaste.it/57jlg)

Note: I have installed Mint 19 version and found the same issue. I just downgraded to Mint 18.3 and CPU and memory usage are fine. Many others also reported the same issue.

Comment: What does mean "can't use web browser"? What happens?

Comment: all browser disappeared ... can't install new one

Comment: What happens why you try to install a new one?

Comment: failed to install.then after i migrated to mint 19 same issue found so downgraded to mint 18.3 now no problem. I think problem with kernel or with new ubuntu version.

Comment: Definitely not with kernel — maybe with systemd. Downgrading the system not really a solution, as it leaves you without all the new performance tweaks and fixes that come with every new version of software *(and Ubuntu is not a rolling-release distro, meaning that, barring a few exceptions like browsers, your software gonna be stuck at a fixed version that only receives security-related patches)*.

Comment: Anyway, on to the topic: you need to describe exactly what happens. "It doesn't work" is not a description. What does it say when it fails to install a new browser? What are reasons that you can't use an old one? Did you try running browser from terminal, does it say something? As it stands your problem is too vague for anyone.

Comment: i have updated the post.. Thank you for the valuable time..

Answer (score 7):

I also faced the same issue after upgrade on my DELL laptop.

#### My workaround

Soon after booting, stopping and starting `systed-udev` eliminates all bind and unbind problems and response drastically improves. I used the following two commands in sequence:

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-udevd systemd-udevd-kernel.socket systemd-udevd-control.socket
sudo systemctl start systemd-udevd systemd-udevd-kernel.socket systemd-udevd-control.socket
```

#### My understanding

Before all hardware is discovered properly, bind/unbind starts executing when no procedures are available and does not get reinitialized. After stopping and starting, it gets all the procedures in place. Probably, this is a boot sequence problem.

Answer (score 4):

laptop Dell vostro 3300

```
:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=cosmic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.10"

:~$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  2
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               37
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 430  @ 2.27GHz
Stepping:            2
CPU MHz:             1570.403
CPU max MHz:         2262,0000
CPU min MHz:         1197,0000
BogoMIPS:            4521.91
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
```

create file in /etc/init.d/

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/systemd-udevd-solv.sh
```

paste -->

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
  start)
    sleep 5
    systemctl stop systemd-udevd systemd-udevd-kernel.socket systemd-udevd-control.socket
    sleep 5
    systemctl start systemd-udevd systemd-udevd-kernel.socket systemd-udevd-control.socket
esac
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to save file and confirm exit

change permission

```
sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/systemd-udevd-solv.sh
```

enable script to run at startup

```
cd /etc/rc3.d
ln -s ../init.d/systemd-udevd-solv.sh S06systemd-udevd-solv
```