# Remove desktop after upgrade to ubuntu 19.10 and not install xfce4

Tags: dpkg, xfce

after I install xfce4 with

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

in the middle of way my net is disconnected and I try to install again but I got error like this:

```
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-fronted
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

after i ran `dpkg --configure -a` I got this error:

```
dpkg: error: unable to access the dpkg database directory /var/lib/dpkg: Read-only file system
```

I reinstall my Linux after login on my Linux but still I cant install any app on my OS I uploaded dmesg.txt file you can download in below link

https://we.tl/t-j8QnIPFahl

and when I use the `sudo mount / -o remount,rw`  command I got that:

```
mount: /: cannot remount /dev/sda7 read-write, is write-protected.
```

Comment: Did you restart the computer and try again? Did you run dpkg with sudo?

Comment: Please post the full output of `dmesg`.

Comment: @Robby1212 yes I did severel time

Comment: @k7AAY I use sudo apt-get install xfce4

Comment: @FliegendeWurst I send all message I can see in display

Comment: Run `dmesg` (or `sudo dmesg`) and post the output of that program.

Comment: @FliegendeWurst that is many messages how can I type that in here?

Comment: Simply copy and paste the output (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176790/how-do-i-paste-long-code-samples-and-terminal-output)

Comment: @FliegendeWurst I don't use VM I installed on my lap top and I don't have desktop to use mouse and copy paste I posted this topic from my cell phone

Comment: You can also upload an image of the screen in that case. You have to pipe the output through `less` (`dmesg | less`) and post at least the last five pages of output (navigate using the page up/down keys).

Comment: I can't send any Image for this: Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

You need at least 10 reputation to post images

Comment: @FliegendeWurst I I uploaded dmesg.txt file you can download it

Comment: You have at least two problems: the file system is only mounted as read-only (usually either broken configuration or broken hardware) and the nvidia driver is loading unsuccessfully. Try disabling or uninstalling the nvidia driver (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035528/ubuntu-18-04-systemd-udevd-uses-high-cpu-conflict-with-nvidia-graphics)

Comment: And it would be useful to see the first pages of dmesg output. Try storing the output in `/tmp`: `dmesg > /tmp/dmesg_out.txt`. You can then copy that to a USB drive: `cp /tmp/dmesg_out.txt /media/<username>/<usbstick>/`

Comment: I use `sudo mv /lib/udev/rules.d/71-nvidia.rules ~` but I got Read only problem: `mv: cannot move '/lib/udev/rules.d/71-nvidia.rules' to '/root/71-nvidia.rules': Read-only file system`