# Probably unnatural battery drain on a Dell XPS 13

Tags: wireless, dell, power-management, battery

Ubuntu 19.10 on Dell XPS 13 here.

Ever since my update to Ubuntu 18.10, the battery drain of my laptop has become very fast. My computer is 2yrs old, so it's maybe unfair to compare its currently battery performance with its earlier one, but it can currently run no longer than 2, 2½ hours.

I've recently observed that its performance is much better if I switch WiFi off. Is it a way to check my impressions? Is it a known bug?

Comment: is it 19.10 or 18.10?

Comment: It's 19.10, but I was having the same issues on 18.10 and 19.04 as well.

Comment: does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028883/ubuntu-18-04-systemd-udevd-uses-high-cpu-conflict-with-wifi) help?

Comment: @DougSmythies Not quite. That page does not really offer a solution, but rather suggests that Bluetooth's the main problem. But empirically I've got the impression that simply deactivating Bluetooth does not help - only deactivating the wireless card does.

Comment: You could monitor processor package power with and without WiFi enabled. If it works with your processor, and it will if Intel and might if AMD, try: `sudo turbostat --quiet --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 15`. turbostat is included in the linux tools common package.

Comment: @DougSmythies Thanks for your suggestion. I've performed the check, but I'm personally not able to decide whether the output is corroborating my suspicion.

Comment: Edit your question, adding the output. Do you see, on average, more processor package power with WiFi enabled?