# XPS 9560 battery drain

Tags: dell, power-management, battery, xps

Summary: suspecting battery drain and (maybe) powertop malfunction.

Ever since I updated to the 19.X series (currently 19.10) I've experienced a very sharp decay in the battery life that I cannot pinpoint ([Probably unnatural battery drain on a Dell XPS 13](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188035/probably-unnatural-battery-drain-on-a-dell-xps-13)). To have an idea, I used to get around 12-10h of mild using and currently have 2h30 top.
 I have activated the TLP and the powertop auto-tune flag, I use only intel drivers and have deactivated Bluetooth for the testing ([Ubuntu 18.04 battery life](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078939/ubuntu-18-04-battery-life)). I have also carefully check that I'm not in fact running Nvidia drivers...
Reducing the screen brightness to the minimum and restarting my machine, at 100% I can get around 10h of an expected lifetime (~8W reported from powertop). Seems good right? Well... To have an idea, I used to get an estimated time around ~9h of MILD use and ~14h for all the settings to the minimum. Currently, I have 2h30 top in mild use.
Part of this is the shitty battery capacity, that after 1.5y is at already at 68%.

The funny part starts where I try to find the culprit and I can't... Below three different situations. Mild use + Skype (background), Mild use and Mild use with wifi off. Here are a couple of points:

- It is clear that keeping skype (or using any other app) spikes the
  consumption but 32W for half a CPU core???? This seems abusive.
- The total CPU usage should not account for the high battery drain.
- A big part of the usage comes from the backlight but I'm not sure if the reported values are correct
- I have read online multiple comments to discarge the powertop readings however, the total consumption seems to be compatible with the real lifetime.

Can you help me find the hidding culprit?

P.S. I consider "Mild use" to have Firefox open and another 3 programs in the background. Screen brightness to 45%.

```
######### Mild use + Skype ############

PowerTOP v2.9     Overview   Idle stats   Frequency stats   Device stats   Tunables                           

The battery reports a discharge rate of 33.1 W
The power consumed was 0.00 J
The estimated remaining time is 0 hours, 38 minutes

Summary: 14022,1 wakeups/second,  0,0 GPU ops/seconds, 0,0 VFS ops/sec and 158,1% CPU use

Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
  13.8 W     43,6%                      Device         Display backlight
 6.57 mW      8,5 pkts/s                Device         Network interface: wlp2s0 (ath10k_pci)
    0 mW    453,8 ms/s     1416,3       Interrupt      [9] acpi
    0 mW    425,9 ms/s     2031,7       Process        [PID 23358] /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux --ty
    0 mW    179,4 ms/s      20,4        Process        [PID 3605] /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
    0 mW    106,9 ms/s      75,7        Process        [PID 5477] /usr/bin/gnome-shell
    0 mW     96,9 ms/s     472,7        Process        [PID 177] [kswapd0]
    0 mW     92,9 ms/s      64,1        Process        [PID 2066] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/webkit2gtk-4.0/Web
    0 mW     74,2 ms/s      27,2        Process        [PID 3604] /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
    0 mW     21,4 ms/s     1018,3       Process        [PID 18700] /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux --ty
    0 mW     12,0 ms/s     176,7        Process        [PID 32697] stremio
    0 mW     11,9 ms/s       5,8        Process        [PID 5250] /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /r
    0 mW      9,7 ms/s     2092,9       Interrupt      [138] nvme0q6
    0 mW      5,8 ms/s      62,1        Process        [PID 25408] powertop
    0 mW      5,4 ms/s       1,9        Process        [PID 7574] /usr/share/mailspring/resources/app.asar.unp
    0 mW      5,4 ms/s     1529,9       Interrupt      [139] nvme0q7
    0 mW      5,3 ms/s      13,6        Process        [PID 7469] Mailspring default
    0 mW      4,6 ms/s      0,00        Interrupt      [9] RCU(softirq)
    0 mW      4,5 ms/s      52,4        Interrupt      [7] sched(softirq)


top - 23:47:25 up 9 days, 11:44,  2 users,  load average: 2,15, 2,46, 2,57
Tasks: 360 total,   1 running, 358 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4,6 us,  7,4 sy,  0,0 ni, 85,2 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  2,8 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  15864,7 total,   1570,7 free,  10760,5 used,   3533,5 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  20480,0 total,  19608,4 free,    871,6 used.   3889,5 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                  
18661 joaosf    20   0 5349912 442928 130812 S  52,3   2,7 119:19.07 skypeforlinux                            
 3605 root      20   0  187308  16336   9168 S  16,3   0,1  51:57.78 cups-browsed                             
 2066 joaosf    20   0  101,7g 380852  50152 S   9,3   2,3 412:09.72 WebKitWebProces                          
 3604 root      20   0   45636  24988   6648 S   7,0   0,2  21:56.28 cupsd                                    
 5477 joaosf    20   0 5219240   1,7g 213996 S   5,0  11,3 259:06.34 gnome-shell                              
 5250 joaosf    20   0  668384 311116 237308 S   3,0   1,9 131:33.21 Xorg                                     
  291 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   1,7   0,0  11:09.92 irq/51-DLL07BE:                          
  310 joaosf    20   0 1858892 279992 155256 S   1,7   1,7  29:04.56 QtWebEngineProc                          
32697 joaosf    20   0 3825848 206192  60948 S   1,7   1,3  19:01.27 stremio                                  
25377 joaosf    20   0  886708  48504  35608 S   1,3   0,3   0:00.89 gnome-terminal-                          
 8546 joaosf    20   0 3568652 303328 110644 S   1,0   1,9  51:06.63 Web Content                              
 2921 joaosf    24   4  959032  97088    104 S   0,7   0,6   9:34.57 WolframKernel                            
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0,3   0,0   4:29.10 rcu_sched                                
 2490 joaosf    20   0 1177004  93892    676 S   0,3   0,6  12:11.55 WolframKernel 


######### Mild use  ############

The battery reports a discharge rate of 14.7 W
The power consumed was 275 J
The estimated remaining time is 1 hours, 25 minutes

Summary: 1834,2 wakeups/second,  0,0 GPU ops/seconds, 0,0 VFS ops/sec and 36,2% CPU use

Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
  7.83 W     43,6%                      Device         Display backlight
  128 mW      5,2 ms/s     397,1        Timer          tick_sched_timer
 63.8 mW      1,9 ms/s     198,2        Interrupt      [17] i2c_designware.1
 47.0 mW      1,0 ms/s     146,0        Interrupt      [136] nvme0q4
 25.7 mW      8,8 ms/s      77,3        Timer          hrtimer_wakeup
 23.3 mW    236,5 µs/s      72,5        Interrupt      [135] nvme0q3
 22.2 mW      1,6 ms/s      68,7        Process        [PID 291] [irq/51-DLL07BE:]
 22.1 mW      9,9 ms/s      65,7        Process        [PID 177] [kswapd0]
 22.0 mW      6,5 ms/s      66,4        Process        [PID 32697] stremio
 19.5 mW     49,3 ms/s      45,3        Process        [PID 5477] /usr/bin/gnome-shell
 16.3 mW    520,3 µs/s      50,6        Interrupt      [138] nvme0q6
 15.9 mW      0,7 ms/s      49,3        Process        [PID 29948] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -chil
 15.1 mW     55,0 ms/s      29,8        Process        [PID 2066] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/webkit2gtk-4.0/Web
 12.7 mW     97,9 ms/s       9,0        Process        [PID 3605] /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
 11.7 mW      1,0 ms/s      36,1        Process        [PID 2634] /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.0/SystemFi
 9.55 mW      0,7 ms/s      29,5        Process        [PID 2927] /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.0/SystemFi
 9.25 mW      1,7 ms/s      28,3        Process        [PID 5260] /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /r
 8.39 mW     41,1 ms/s      13,3        Process        [PID 3604] /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
 8.18 mW    594,4 µs/s      25,3        Process        [PID 2490] /usr/local/W



Tasks: 357 total,   1 running, 355 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4,0 us,  1,3 sy,  0,0 ni, 94,2 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,5 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  15864,7 total,   2689,5 free,  10461,9 used,   2713,3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  20480,0 total,  19587,1 free,    892,9 used.   4032,4 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                  
 3605 root      20   0  187308  16116   8948 S  15,9   0,1  52:36.40 cups-browsed                             
 2066 joaosf    20   0  101,7g 379700  49000 S  12,3   2,3 412:36.80 WebKitWebProces                          
 3604 root      20   0   45636  24988   6648 S   7,3   0,2  22:13.21 cupsd                                    
32697 joaosf    20   0 3825848 200392  55148 S   1,7   1,2  19:05.32 stremio                                  
  310 joaosf    20   0 1858892 278708 153972 S   1,3   1,7  29:07.25 QtWebEngineProc                          
 5477 joaosf    20   0 5219092   1,7g 205208 S   1,0  11,2 259:27.21 gnome-shell                              
 2924 joaosf    24   4  969916 105972    104 S   0,7   0,7   9:36.64 WolframKernel                            
 3330 joaosf    20   0  851684 125892  19344 S   0,7   0,8  20:37.23 atom                                     
 8439 joaosf    20   0 4414144 560172  82436 S   0,7   3,4 121:22.28 firefox                                  
 8546 joaosf    20   0 3560036 286140  90876 S   0,7   1,8  51:08.26 Web Content                              
 8662 joaosf    20   0 3647512 257052 106072 S   0,7   1,6 209:07.81 Web Content                              
17359 joaosf    20   0 1540156  57572  24468 S   0,7   0,4   0:29.75 nautilus                                 
  959 root      20   0    2528     80     24 S   0,3   0,0   0:14.03 acpid                                    
 2634 joaosf    20   0 2419132 259004   2412 S   0,3   1,6  16:14.58 WolframKernel                            
 2918 joaosf    24   4  958996  97052    104 S   0,3   0,6   9:29.46 WolframKernel                            
 2921 joaosf    24   4  959032  97088    104 S   0,3   0,6   9:35.05 WolframKernel                            
 3382 joaosf    20   0  801660 172924  27956 S   0,3   1,1   2:18.30 atom                                     
 5250 joaosf    20   0  668156 310800 236992 S   0,3   1,9 131:40.39 Xorg                                     
 7469 joaosf    20   0  759928 171780  61492 S   0,3   1,1   1:35.38 Mailspring defa                          
25377 joaosf    20   0  886708  39084  26036 S   0,3   0,2   0:02.40 gnome-terminal-                          
26392 joaosf    20   0   12068   4056   3284 R   0,3   0,0   0:00.03 top                                      
    1 root      20   0  168400   7416   4196 S   0,0   0,0   7:05.72 systemd                                  
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.12 kthreadd     

######### Mild use - Wifi ############

The battery reports a discharge rate of 13.6 W
The power consumed was 306 J
The estimated remaining time is 0 hours, 38 minutes

Summary: 1792,5 wakeups/second,  0,0 GPU ops/seconds, 0,0 VFS ops/sec and 39,0% CPU use

Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
  10.1 W     43,6%                      Device         Display backlight
 96.6 mW      6,3 ms/s     497,9        Timer          tick_sched_timer
 23.7 mW      8,9 ms/s     122,0        Timer          hrtimer_wakeup
 23.4 mW     60,7 ms/s     120,4        Process        [PID 8736] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 6 -isF
 19.9 mW      2,1 ms/s     102,8        Interrupt      [17] i2c_designware.1
 19.4 mW      5,8 ms/s      99,9        Process        [PID 8451] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -new-window
 12.4 mW      1,8 ms/s      64,1        Process        [PID 8507] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -new-window
 11.8 mW     16,3 ms/s      60,9        Process        [PID 8439] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -new-window
 10.7 mW      6,6 ms/s      55,3        Process        [PID 32697] stremio
 6.56 mW      1,2 ms/s      33,8        Process        [PID 2634] /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.0/SystemFiles/Kerne
 6.54 mW      1,5 ms/s      33,7        Process        [PID 8784] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 6 -isF
 6.40 mW      2,2 ms/s      33,0        Process        [PID 8508] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -parentBuildID
 6.39 mW     28,7 ms/s      32,9        Process        [PID 5477] /usr/bin/gnome-shell
 5.79 mW    661,2 µs/s      29,8        Process        [PID 29948] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 -is
 5.74 mW    667,2 µs/s      29,6        Process        [PID 22742] /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 -is
 5.03 mW    404,9 µs/s      25,9        Process        [PID 2921] /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.0/SystemFiles/Kerne
 4.28 mW    663,5 µs/s      22,0        Process        [PID 2490] /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.0/SystemFiles/Kerne
 4.26 mW    205,7 µs/s      21,9        Process        [PID 11] [rcu_sched]
 4.24 mW    688,1 µs/s      21,8        Process        [PID 2924] /usr/local/Wolfram/M

Tasks: 366 total,   2 running, 363 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s):  9,1 us,  2,6 sy,  0,0 ni, 86,3 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  2,0 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  15864,7 total,   2496,7 free,  10495,4 used,   2872,6 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  20480,0 total,  19709,9 free,    770,1 used.   3895,3 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                           
 3605 root      20   0  187308  16116   8948 S  22,8   0,1  53:10.83 cups-browsed                                      
 2066 joaosf    20   0  101,7g 379700  49000 R  16,9   2,3 413:07.81 WebKitWebProces                                   
 5477 joaosf    20   0 5219312   1,7g 206440 S  16,6  11,2 259:49.66 gnome-shell                                       
 3604 root      20   0   45636  24988   6648 S  11,6   0,2  22:30.04 cupsd                                             
 5250 joaosf    20   0  671908 314700 240892 S   6,6   1,9 131:49.39 Xorg                                              
25377 joaosf    20   0  886708  39084  26036 S   3,0   0,2   0:02.83 gnome-terminal-                                   
32697 joaosf    20   0 3825848 200392  55148 S   2,3   1,2  19:09.69 stremio                                           
 8439 joaosf    20   0 4416520 650656  85484 S   1,7   4,0 121:43.11 firefox                                           
  310 joaosf    20   0 1858892 278976 154360 S   1,3   1,7  29:10.04 QtWebEngineProc                                   
 6042 joaosf    20   0    9032   2836   2428 S   1,3   0,0  11:00.54 libinput-debug-                                   
 3330 joaosf    20   0  852708 126468  19692 S   1,0   0,8  20:38.90 atom                                              
 8546 joaosf    20   0 3560036 282488  90980 S   1,0   1,7  51:09.84 Web Content                                       
 8605 joaosf    20   0 3115348 412532  50196 S   1,0   2,5   9:06.44 WebExtensions                                     
  291 root     -51   0       0      0      0 D   0,7   0,0  11:12.25 irq/51-DLL07BE:                                   
  809 systemd+  20   0   21156   4540   3784 S   0,7   0,0   0:50.59 systemd-resolve                                   
 8736 joaosf    20   0 3382140 311712 132488 S   0,7   1,9  16:48.73 Web Content                                       
  386 root      20   0   21388   2528   1988 S   0,3   0,0   0:05.82 systemd-udevd                                     
 2030 joaosf    20   0   83,4g 136312  61880 S   0,3   0,8  16:58.04 epiphany                                          
 2490 joaosf    20   0 1177004  93888    672 S   0,3   0,6  12:12.80 WolframKernel                                     
 2634 joaosf    20   0 2419132 259004   2412 S   0,3   1,6  16:15.39 WolframKernel                                     
 2814 joaosf    20   0 4142416 231884   1884 S   0,3   1,4   8:24.82 java                                              
 2918 joaosf    24   4  958996  97052    104 S   0,3   0,6   9:29.91 WolframKernel                                     
 2921 joaosf    24   4  959032  97088    104 S   0,3   0,6   9:35.51 WolframKernel
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, the Li-ion rechargeable batteries got 25% less life after 500 times use in general condition, that's about 1.5 years And laptops guess the battery condition by voltage because no one can determine X mW left in it. (with the special machine yes), thus 2h30m sounds normal to me. This is a first part of the problem

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka Indeed that estimate agrees with the reported battery capacity. The real problem is that a 30% drop does not fully account for the effective ~60% drop in battery life. I know this problem is somewhat ill-defined but I truly feel a large drop in battery life as was already reported by other users.

Comment: I see the new Skype update coming today, hope it gets better.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with dell xps 9700 in Opensuse - total consumption being at 17W
My advice : try fedora 34 it is much much better - as low as 3.14W on idle !

I suspected powertop miscalculation but laptop stays cool as ice in Fedora and real work time is 500% better !